# Make Container the same size of image in a different widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget, flutter-widget

I have a card widget which can be flipped. Image on the front side and text on the back.
The problem is that the images can be uploaded by the user, so sizes can vary.
How can I rescale the Container with the text to be the same size as the provided image?
Right now the container takes up all the space it can get, whereas the image is a bit smaller.

Code:

```
 Widget getCardSide(isFlipped) {
    if (isFlipped) {
      return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Text(widget.title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: textColor,
                        fontSize: 45,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: Text(widget.text,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ));
    } else {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Image.file(
          widget.image,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

So how do I resize the container in the If-Block to the same size as the image in the Else-Block?

Comment: Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/boxy which can do some pretty amazing layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of different things, this seems to fix it:

```
return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: FileImage(widget.image),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

That way the Image is scaled to the same size as the other container, although it cuts up the edges. Not exactly what I wanted but that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

remove

> alignment: Alignment.center, from the image.. replace your code with this

```
 Widget getCardSide(isFlipped) {
if (isFlipped) {
  return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Text(widget.title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: textColor,
                    fontSize: 45,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: Text(widget.text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: textColor,
                  fontSize: 25,
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ));
} else {
  return Container(
 
    child: Expand(
       child: Image.file(
      widget.image,
    ),
   )
  );
}
```

}

Comment: Removing the alignment only moves the image up. It's still smaller than the text container though

Comment: use expand to fill the container ... I have updated the code.. If you need a fix width and height, you can add it to the container